# Timeout if server does not answer

Tags: ios, swift, timeout, reachability

I have code in my VC like this :

```
    if Reachability.isConnectedToNetwork() == true {
        print("Internet connection OK")

         JSONParseFunc()

    } else {
        print("Internet connection FAILED")
        let alert = UIAlertView(title: "you're not conneted to internet ", message: "make sure you're connected to server ", delegate: nil, cancelButtonTitle: "OK")
        alert.show()
    }
```

in which I check the reachability of internet, but I want to check if the server is sending data or not, I need to set timeout for this purpose, how do I achieve time out in this code here is my JSON function:

```
func JSONParseFunc(){



        let requestURL: NSURL = NSURL(string: "XXXXXXX")!
        let urlRequest: NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(url: requestURL as URL)
        let session = URLSession.shared
        let task = session.dataTask(with: urlRequest as URLRequest) {
            (data, response, error) -> Void in


            let readableJSON = JSON(data: data! , options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers, error: nil)

            self.nrows = readableJSON.count

            for i in 0...self.nrows{

                if let Name = readableJSON[i]["Name"].string as String! {
                    var ID = readableJSON[i]["Id"].intValue
                    var iDString = String (ID)

                    var desc = readableJSON[i]["Description"].string as String!


                    self.iDArray.append(iDString)

                    self.description1.append(desc!)
                    self.namesArray.append(Name)


                }




            }

            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
        task.resume()

    self.tableView.reloadData()


    }
```

Comment: (NS)URLRequest has a timeoutInterval property ...

Comment: where should I put that in my code ?

Comment: What do *you* think? – You might also consider to use `URLRequest` instead of `NSMutableURLRequest` in Swift 3.

Comment: Btw, have a look at [Connect Without Preflight](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/NetworkingOverview/UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition/UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010220-CH213-SW25): Checking for an Internet connection *before* attempting to make a connection is *not* recommended.

Comment: Could I check the reachability with my host name in the first place instead ? @MartinR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to set this one like that

```
 var session = URLSession()
 override init() {
        let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
        configuration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 30.0
        configuration.timeoutIntervalForResource = 60.0
        session = URLSession(configuration: configuration)

    }
```

Comment: are you getting the response from server?

Comment: Okay just check readableJSON is empty or not if readableJSON is dictionary then check like readableJSON.isEmpty{} if not empty then go ahead if empty then just return

Comment: Ok so check your if data != nil before doing the serilization

Comment: WOaaaah Thanks a million it worked, so this way I do not need to chech if the server response right ?

Comment: @UncleJunior but suppose if server take the time for sending the response then we can use Timeoutinterval

Comment: if my answer is acceptable then please accept my answer and upvote me

Comment: I have accept the answer but sorry I dont have enough reputation to upvote I wish I could do that, because you helped me alot and it take your time thanks

Comment: @UncleJunior it's my Pleasure to help you :)Happy coding